# Check if my matrix is magic square

Tags: c

So I have this matrix:

```
8       1       6

3       5       7

4       9       2
```

And now I want to check if this is a "magic square". This means that the sums of all the rows, columns and oblique lines respectively, are equal (here with value of 15).

So because I want to do that as efficiently as possible and I need to print my matrix first, I want to do all the values checks in the same function:

```
void printmatrix(int *mat, int dimension) {

    int i, j, rowscount, colcount;
    int firstvalue = 0; 
    int ismagicsquaere = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        rowscount = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
        {
            int num = *(mat + i * dimension + j);

            if (i == 0)
                firstvalue += num;
            else
                rowscount += num;

            printf("%d\t", num);
        }

        if (rowscount != firstvalue)
            ismagicsquaere = 0;

        printf("\n\n");
    }
```

Currently my function checks only the rows value. I wonder if it is also possible to check the columns and the oblique lines?

Comment: Possible? Definitely.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Add SUM in your question statement, its unclear and YES it is possible.

Comment: If the rows and columns fill the "magic" critera, wouldn't the diagonal always do this too?

Comment: @Lundin: No: [1 2 3] [2 4 0] [3 0 3] - the rows and columns each sum to 6, but the diagonals are 8 and 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing everything within the nested `for` loops is an interesting problem.

The only small challenge was to calculate the *columns* sums as well, since, the way the loops are written, it seems at first an *array[dimension]* would be necessary.

However a small trick is of help. This line to get a row value

```
int rownum = *(mat + i * dimension + j);
```

Might also be used to get the col value, by inverting `i` and `j`

```
int colnum = *(mat + j * dimension + i);
```

Allowing to sum the columns as well at the same place (a matrix being a square!)

```
void printmatrix(int *mat, int dimension) {

    int i, j;
    int magic=1;              // default to "is magic"
    int d1=0,d2=0,refcount=0; // diag1, diag2

    for (i = 0 ; i < dimension; i++) {
        int rowcount = 0;
        int colcount = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
            int num = *(mat + i * dimension + j);
            rowcount += num;                   // row sum 
            if (i == j) d1 += num;             // diag1 sum
            if (i == dimension-j-1) d2 += num; // diag2 sum
            // row to col ...
            colcount += *(mat + j * dimension + i); // col sum
        }
        if (!i) refcount = rowcount;   // first rowcount is reference
        else if (refcount != rowcount) magic = 0;
        if (refcount != colcount) magic = 0;
    }
    if (d1 != refcount || d2 != refcount) magic = 0;
    printf("Is Magic: %s\n", magic ? "Yes":"No");
}
```

Comment: "I want to do that as efficiently as possible". This code is very branch-intense. Showing everything into a single loop for the sake of it is a meta requirement, it fills no purpose by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to iterate through the matrix 3 times, with 3 separate loops. I see no way around this.

The "naive" implementation:

- Sum the first row and store this result in a variable to henceforth use for comparisons.
- Sum the rest of the rows in a loop and compare against the variable. If any sums are unequal, return false from the function.
- Second loop, check the columns, compare against the same variable, if any unequal, return false.
- Third loops, check the diagonal, compare against the same variable, if any unequal, return false.

This algorithm is however potentially ineffective because it is very branch-intensive. What you can do to manually optimize it is to reduce the number of branches.

One possibly faster implementation:

- Sum all rows, store results in a result array. This is cache-friendly and will mean that the array ends up in data cache.
- Do the same with columns and diagonals.
- Make sure that your 3 sum arrays are allocated adjacently in memory by placing them in a struct. This is cache-friendly. Preferably something like this:

  ```
  typedef union
  {
    struct
    {
      unsigned int row_sum[3];
      unsigned int col_sum[3];
      unsigned int dia_sum[2];
    };
    unsigned int sum [3+3+2];
  } sum_t;  

  _Static_assert(sizeof(sum_t) == sizeof(unsigned int[3+3+2]), 
                 "Sorry, weird systems are not supported.");
  ```
- After done summing, go through the above `sum` array and compare every item against the first.

This may or may not improve performance. You have to benchmark it on the specific system.

Comment: There is no need for three separate loops, as the rows and columns can be handled within the same two nested loops (see my suggested code). The diagonals could be handled within those as well, but would require undesired if clauses. Furthermore, I doubt storing the sums will be faster than in place checking, not only because it does not allow for early returning.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code is buggy, as you start with `ismagicsquaere = 0`. But even if you start with `ismagicsquaere = 1`, it is still buggy, because in the iteration `i = 0`, the variable `rowscount` remains zero, so that the following comparison will always lead to setting `ismagicsquaere = 0`, which is not what you want.
2. If you are aiming at speed, you should whenever possible avoid any if clause within a loop, in particular within the inner loop.
3. Since you have a printf in your inner loop, I wouldn't care about speed at all, as this I/O operation will by far dominate the runtime.
4. If your aim really was a fast magic square check, you would have not only to remove the printf calls but return the function as soon as the first check fails.

Here is my suggested code, including checks for the two diagonals. Since I assume that you need the printing to be included, I left the printf calls and did not add early returning:

```
void printmatrix(const int *mat, int dimension) {
    int i, j;
    int ismagicsquare = 1;
    int diagonal1 = 0, diagonal2 = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        diagonal1 += mat[i * dimension + i];
        diagonal2 += mat[i * dimension + dimension - 1 - i];
    }

    if (diagonal1 != diagonal2) {
        ismagicsquare = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        int rowscount = 0;
        int colscount = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
            rowscount += mat[i * dimension + j];
            colscount += mat[j * dimension + i];

            printf("%d\t", mat[i * dimension + j]);
        }

        if (rowscount != diagonal1 || colscount != diagonal1) {
            ismagicsquare = 0;
        }

        printf("\n\n");
    }

    printf("ismagicsquare = %i\n", ismagicsquare);
}
```

Note that with regard to memory accesses and cache optimization, it should be fastest to do in place checking of the row sums as shown, but within the same two nested loops increment per-column sums and evaluate them at the end. This way the very cache-unfriendly memory access mat[j * dimension + i] would be completely removed. However, this kind of optimization only makes sense when designing a pure check function without printf calls.

Answer (score 0):

I've written the following code with the purpose to write (a day) a code that elaborates magic squares.

It stores all rows, columns and diagonals sums into a matrix. The purpose of this matrix ( `sum[][]` ) shall be to understand where the magic square is not correct.

The main calls the function `checkAndComputeSums()`that calculates all sums and returns 1 if the data into  the magic square are correct and 0 if are not correct.

Here the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIMS 3
#define COLS DIMS
#define ROWS DIMS

int checkAndComputeSums(int *s , int *ms, int dim);

enum STYPE {
    SUMROW,
    SUMCOL,
    SUMDIAG,

    //-------------------

    SUMCNT
};

int msqr[COLS][ROWS] = {
    { 8,       1,       6},

    { 3,       5,       7},

    { 4,       9,       2}
};

int sum[DIMS][SUMCNT];

const char * label[SUMCNT] = {
    "ROWS","COLS","DIAG"
};

int checkAndComputeSums(int *s , int *ms, int dim)
{
    int i,j,ok=1;

    /* The sum are cleared */
    for(i=0;i<dim;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<SUMCNT;j++) {
            s[i*SUMCNT+j] =0;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<dim;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<dim;j++) {
            s[i*SUMCNT+SUMROW]+=ms[i*dim+j];
            s[i*SUMCNT+SUMCOL]+=ms[j*dim+i];

            if (i==j)
                s[SUMDIAG]+=ms[i*dim+j];

            if (i==dim - j - 1)
                s[SUMDIAG+SUMCNT]+=ms[i*dim+j];

        }

        if (s[i*SUMCNT+SUMROW]!=s[SUMROW] || s[i*SUMCNT+SUMCOL]!=s[SUMROW])
            ok=0;
    }

    if (s[SUMDIAG]!=s[SUMROW] || s[SUMDIAG+SUMCNT]!=s[SUMROW])
        ok=0;

    return ok;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i,j;

    i=checkAndComputeSums(sum[0],msqr[0],DIMS);
    printf("The check was %s\n",(!i)?"KO":"OK");

    for (j=SUMROW;j<SUMCNT;j++) {
        printf("%s: ",label[j]);
        for(i=0;i<DIMS-((j==SUMDIAG)?1:0);i++) {
            printf("%d ",sum[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```