# How to test hexadecimal string from textfile?

Tags: c, matrix, hex

```
bool testMagicSquare(string str) {
  int length, sum = 0;
  length = strlen(str);

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    sum = sum + str[i];
  }
  if (sum == 120) {
    return 1;
  }

  else return 0;
}
```

My assignment is to get a hexadecimal square from a textfile, test to see if it's a "Magic Square".  If yes, print the square in another textfile to save it.
Get the textfile and print to a file is working but I'm stuck with the testing.

Any ideas?

Example of hexadecimal string: 8 3 4 f 5 e 9 2 b 0 7 c 6 d a 1

Comment: If the square is based on HEX number with a single digit you may sum the ASCII value as you are doing in your code! To verify if is a magic square you may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555212/check-if-my-matrix-is-magic-square/47557532#47557532 . This code is for decimal numbers, but indicates you how to verify if the numbers represent a magic square.

Comment: The only condition to be magical, is a sum of 120?

Comment: To covert the hexadecimal  `char` or `str[i]` as "0-9a-fA-F" into its value. `int val = strtol((char []){str[i], '\0'}, NULL, 16);`

Comment: Or leave as ASCII and use `if (length == 16 && sum == '0'+'1'+... + 'f')`.  This later method can get fooled though

Comment: A "Magic Squares" always 4x4?

Comment: The rules for this assignment is the square should be 4 x 4 where each hexa should only be used once. Row = 30, column = 30 and diagonal = 30. Sum square if always 120, since sum of 0-F  = 120.

Comment: Suggest adding test `length == 16`.

Comment: If you take a look to the code I indicate you in the first message you may obtain your code with simple modifications ... :)

Comment: If test made to insure "each hexa should only be used once. Row = 30, column = 30 and diagonal = 30.", then "Sum square if always 120" test is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for answers. So converting the hexa values to deci values and then check the square would be the easiest way?

Comment: I already have the code to test a "manually" written square. Just need help to test a string the same way

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It's runs only for one digit HEX numbers!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define DIMS 4
#define COLS DIMS
#define ROWS DIMS

int convertChar(unsigned char v);
int checkAndComputeSums(int *s , unsigned char *ms, int dim);

enum STYPE {
    SUMROW,
    SUMCOL,
    SUMDIAG,

    //-------------------

    SUMCNT
};

unsigned char msqr[COLS][ROWS] = {
    {'8','3','4','F'},
    {'5','E','9','2'},
    {'B','0','7','C'},
    {'6','D','A','1'}
};

int sum[DIMS][SUMCNT];

const char * label[SUMCNT] = {
    "ROWS","COLS","DIAG"
};

int convertChar(unsigned char v)
{
    int x;

    x = toupper((int)v);
    x -= 48; /* 48 is the ASCII code of the char 0 */
    if (x>9) x-=7;

    return x;
}

int checkAndComputeSums(int *s , unsigned char *ms, int dim)
{
    int i,j,ok=1;

    /* The sum are cleared */
    for(i=0;i<dim;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<SUMCNT;j++) {
            s[i*SUMCNT+j] =0;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<dim;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<dim;j++) {
            s[i*SUMCNT+SUMROW]+=convertChar(ms[i*dim+j]);
            s[i*SUMCNT+SUMCOL]+=convertChar(ms[j*dim+i]);

            if (i==j)
                s[SUMDIAG]+=convertChar(ms[i*dim+j]);

            if (i==dim - j - 1)
                s[SUMDIAG+SUMCNT]+=convertChar(ms[i*dim+j]);

        }

        if (s[i*SUMCNT+SUMROW]!=s[SUMROW] || s[i*SUMCNT+SUMCOL]!=s[SUMROW])
            ok=0;
    }

    if (s[SUMDIAG]!=s[SUMROW] || s[SUMDIAG+SUMCNT]!=s[SUMROW])
        ok=0;

    return ok;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i,j;

    i=checkAndComputeSums(sum[0],msqr[0],DIMS);
    printf("The check was %s\n",(!i)?"KO":"OK");

    for (j=SUMROW;j<SUMCNT;j++) {
        printf("%s: ",label[j]);
        for(i=0;i<DIMS-((j==SUMDIAG)?2:0);i++) {
            printf("%d ",sum[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }

    return 0;
}
```